# find $\left \| {N}' \right \|$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\gamma :I\rightarrow R^{3}$ be a parameterized curve by Arc Length with curvature $\left \| k \right \|=2$ and torsion $\left \|t  \right \|=3$ then find  $\left \| {N}' \right \|$

i tried using frenet formulas but i can only get that $ \left \| {N}' \right \|=\left \| -kT+tB \right \|\leq \left \| -kT \right \|+\left \| tB \right \|\leq 5$

by the fundamental theorem I know this is a propeller?(I don't know how it's called in English) but I don't know if it helps somewhere

Answer (score 1):

You can do better than the triangle inequality (which you did wrong, by the way). Actually compute the length of that sum of vectors. What do you know about $T$ and $B$?

Comment: They are linearly independent vectors. Why is the inequality wrong?

Comment: Since when is $5=1$? You need to reread carefully. You know lots more than linear independence.

Comment: I know they are perpendicular, I am trying this problem for 2 days in this point I know I am missing something I can't see. (well 5=1 in mod4, just a joke.)

Comment: So either dot the vector with itself or use the Pythagorean Theorem!

Comment: This is seriously wrong. If you're not using what you were given, it almost surely cannot be a valid solution. How can you pretend to conclude that $N’=0$ when your original equation clearly says it is not?

Comment: But if I use the dot product I will have $(-kT+tB)\cdot {N}'$ how do I compute that

Comment: Your background is very weak. Dot the vector with *itself*.

Comment: That was an unnecessary comment in my opinion even if  its true, i am trying really hard. Anyway thanks for your time.